# How can be shown manyTomany field values into a single text box in django template

Tags: python, html, django

I want to show manytomany field value into a single  input textbox in django template.
My output is
ABC /n
Abc /n
BVC /n

i want like ABC ,Abc,BVC

my code sample is this

```
    <div class='col-sm-8'>
{% for car in cars %}<br/>
      <input type='text' class='form-control' name='cars' placeholder='Select cars' value= {{car}}> 
{% endfor %}
      </div>
```

I want to show the output in Textbox field

Answer (score 0):

You can do it:

from python: (views.py)

```
...
data_input = ', '.join([car for car in cars])
...
```

and in your template:

```
  <div class='col-sm-8'>
     <input type='text' class='form-control' name='cars' placeholder='Select cars' value= "{{ data_input }}"> 
  </div>
```

Comment: it shows me a error `'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable` for views file

Comment: remember that car would be queryset, so... do it... `cars = YourModelCar.ManyToManyRelation.all()` to iterate..